# best way to load binary WebGL model through ajax?

Tags: ajax, webgl

I've been developing a web-based 3D application using WebGL. 
On the server side a binary 3D model is generated which is downloaded by the client using AJAX. Models can be quite large ( > 200K) and thus I want to avoid sending them in text format. Currently I use the following code to achieve this:

```
stream = http.responseText; // results of ajax request
..... 
var len = stream.length;
var header_size = 4 + 4 + 4*2; 
var buf_sz = len + 16;
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(buf_sz);
var bytes = new Uint8Array(buf, 0, buf_sz);

for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bytes[i] = stream.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
}
....    
// use these to initialize WebGL buffers
var verts = new Float32Array(buf, bytes_skip, n_verts*3);
var normals = new Float32Array(buf, bytes_skip + n_verts*12, n_verts*3);
var indices = new Uint16Array(buf, bytes_skip + n_verts*24, n_indices);
...
```

while, on the server side, I send the data with 'charset=x-user-defined'

In other words, I basically had to copy the data from 'stream' char-by-char to initialize the arraybuffer. I wonder if there is a better (more direct) way to do this ? maybe instantiate arraybuffer directly from stream ?..

ps. I know there is also jDataView library but it basically does the same

Comment: First off, I've learned something examining the bit wise & here.

Comment: First off, I've learned something examining the bit wise & here.  From PHP I can tell you anytime you can use a natural functional "method/function" the better.  I wrote a bench mark comparing a php array_filter vs a traditional for loop, and the resource AND time usage was better by about a factor of 2 for the array_filter approach.  From the hip try.... bytes = stream.map(function(where){charCodeAt(where) & 0xff};);  I know this does not change the fundamental approach to you algorithm.  But it is possible this will make it better by a factor of 2, more or less.

Comment: huh interesting idea.. as C++ programmer I honestly not very advanced in javascript. I will try this out.

Comment: I suggest a brief look into scheme, of which javascript borrows a significant amount of ideas.  On some further examination though, it is entirely possible javascript did not quite get .map correct, I don't know. In any regard, "tail call recursion" is a truly awesome idea and to ignore it is dumb.  I can tell you are of the C++ school, those guys are bright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like the code snippet below to get the data as a binary array (Code example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
xhr.open("GET", url, true);  
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";   
xhr.onload = function(e) {  
  var arraybuffer = xhr.response; // not responseText  
  /* ... */  
}  
xhr.send();
```

Comment: You can also process the "arraybuffer" with a DataView class... Also, from the server side try to use Content-type: application/octet-stream and transfer using binary data directly, no need to do a char-by-char representation.

Comment: thanks, very interesting.. I did not know that AJAX has a specific option for that. I wonder does it work in other browsers (eg. Chrome) as well ?

Comment: @Chiguireitor: on the server side I do the followng:

fprintf(cgiOut, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=x-user-defined\r\n\r\n");

does it differ in the way how data is encoded ?

Comment: Yes it differs a lot, for starters, some browsers implement different semantics for "text/*" content types. You should use "application/octet-stream" so browsers don't interpret your data as text. That way has worked for me in my binary loader. Also, all this works on Chrome and Firefox.